# \pdfliteral inside table

Tags: tables

I want to write dotted words inside a table.

But using `\pdfliteral` inside a table, ruins the formation of the table.

Does anybody have a solution?

```
 \documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \pdfliteral{q 1 Tr .5 w [0.5 0.5] 0d}{arg1}\pdfliteral{Q}&d&d&d\\\hline
            \_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_\\\hline
            \_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_\\\hline
            \_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: try `\pdfliteral page {...}` (in both instances).

Comment: @Robert I didn't really get your answer, could you write a complete line.

Comment: @Robert please make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I already provided an answer to your crosspost at [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/), here is it again. My answer to [LC: \pdfliteral inside table](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=27687) uses the same solution as Robert commented earlier: using the `page` option.

With pdfTeX version 1.30.0 or later, you can the optional `page` argument. So that literal code refers to the origin (bottom-left corner of the page) and can be enclosed with q Q.

See pdfTeX manual (`texdoc pdftex`) section *7.14 Literals and specials*.

Working code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]\centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \pdfliteral page {q 1 Tr .5 w [0.5 0.5] 0d}{arg1}\pdfliteral page {Q}&d&d&d\\\hline
            \_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_\\\hline
            \_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_\\\hline
            \_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_ &\_\_\_\_\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Just a "thank you" would be discouraged; use an upvote, accept, or bounty. Providing constructive feedback or commentary is fine. Please accept helpful answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer